# private and public field in Django REST Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to have a list of public and private recipes, hiding all private recipes unless it's owner's. I created a manager for this:

```
class RecipeManager(models.Manager):

    def public_recipes(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(RecipeManager, self).filter(private=False)

    def private_recipes(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user')
        return super(RecipeManager, self).filter(private=True, user=user)


class Recipe(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    recipe = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    private = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

views.py:

```
class RecipeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Recipe.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RecipeSerializer
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
```

serializers.py:

```
class RecipeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Recipe
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'recipe', 'total_ingredients')
        depth = 1
```

So, where can I use the methods `public_recipes`, `private_recipes` or is there a better solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you may want to set your custom manager as the default manager of your Recipe model, like so:

```
class RecipeManager(models.Manager):

    def public_recipes(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(RecipeManager, self).filter(private=False)

    def private_recipes(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user')
        return super(RecipeManager, self).filter(private=True, user=user)


class Recipe(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    recipe = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    private = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = RecipeManager()  # Make this manager the default manager
```

You may override the `get_queryset()` method on your view to merge the private and public recipes for a user:

```
class RecipeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Recipe.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RecipeSerializer
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.request.user:
            private_recipes = Recipe.objects.private_recipes(user=self.request.user)
        else:
            private_recipes = Recipe.objects.none()

        public_recipes = Recipe.objects.public_recipes()

        final_recipes_list = private_recipes | public_recipes # Shorthand to merge two querysets
        return final_recipes_list
```

I would actually recommend considering having different ViewSet's for public and private recipes, i.e.

```
class PublicRecipeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Recipe.objects.public_recipes()

class PrivateRecipeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Recipe.objects.filter(private=True)

    def get_queryset(self):
        if not self.request.user:
            raise AuthenticationFailed()

        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        return queryset.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

Comment: so if I have two viewsets, is it possiblie to register them under one url?

Comment: Nah that doesn't really work in practice, if you want to use two viewsets you would probably have two different urls, e.g. `/api/recipes/public/` and `/api/receipes/private/` then you can merge the results in javascript if you need to.

Comment: I actually ended up registering them under `/recipes` and `/my_recipes`. Thanks for help!